# Using google map in my website (https secured) shows error

Tags: google-maps, https

My website uses https secure pages, but when I use Google map API to bring in a map inside my website, it shows error (like webpage contains insecure items).But if I removed this Gmap api the error is gone.

Is there any way like I can use google map in https secured pages without any errors like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes,

> As such we are happy to offer free
>   access to the Maps API v3, Static Maps
>   API, and Maps API Web Services over
>   HTTPS to all developers from today. To
>   load the Maps API v3 over HTTPS, the
>   API must be loaded from the hostname
>   maps-api-ssl.google.com. For the
>   Static Maps API and Web Services,
>   please use maps.googleapis.com.

Check out this official announcement from Google:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/03/maps-apis-over-ssl-now-available-to-all.html

Comment: Although loading the maps services from hostname maps-api-ssl.google.com is indeed a solution, it does not fix the reported error in all cases, I am loading the google maps scripts from maps-api-ssl.google.com and still getting the 'Mixed Content' error

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is if you use [Google Maps - SSL API](https://maps-api-ssl.google.com) you will still sometimes get the  Secure and Unsecured alert. Here is why:

Google url above displays everything under https:// to correctly display the under secured environment. **However** and this is a **huge however issue** Google now displays a picture of the building or location off to the left **without https** thus giving us the **unsecured error we hate to get** in a secured environment.

Here is a good example...take a look at the following:

[https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps?q=1000+Ballpark+Way,+Arlington,+TX&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=49.310476,101.425781&vpsrc=0&hnear=1000+Ballpark+Way,+Arlington,+Texas+76011&t=m&z=17](https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps?q=1000%20Ballpark%20Way,%20Arlington,%20TX&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=49.310476,101.425781&vpsrc=0&hnear=1000%20Ballpark%20Way,%20Arlington,%20Texas%2076011&t=m&z=17)

Now using **Firefox** or browser of your choice, right-click on the building image Info or Image Properties... and WOW! You will see that this image is causing your **unsecured** error when everything according to Google should be all secured behind the Google https://

**The building and location images are not listed under https:// .... you will still get an error!**

Check it out for yourself and you'll see what I'm seeing... so viewing Google maps behind SSL is still an issue unless someone knows of a work-a-round to get those location or building images removed or to be displayed behind https:// and not http:// such as the case below with the image itself.

Bottom line is... this is still an issue because of the **photo images** are **not** behind SSL...
Test it and you will see what I am talking about.

If anyone knows of a work-a-round for this, I'd sure like to know. Google if you have an explanation for this please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use protocol-relative paths like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//example.com/style.css">
<script src="//example.com/script.js"></script>
```

check this answer:

How to Include CSS and JS files via HTTPS when needed?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use google enterprise maps for this and thats not free.
Check out more - http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html

You can try to load the Maps API v3 over HTTPS, the API must be loaded from the hostname maps-api-ssl.google.com. For the Static Maps API and Web Services, please use maps.googleapis.com.

Comment: False; check out the article by Google: Maps APIs over SSL now available to all from Tuesday, March 15, 2011